# Extjs6 : Get Clipboard data on Keydown event of combobox

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, combobox, extjs5

**I need to have access to the clipboard Data on keydown event in Extjs Combobox, to perform some operation.**
I tried with window.clipboardData.
Please find the fiddle : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1cc2

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Tag',{
    renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
    createNewOnEnter:true,
    store:[1,2,3],
    enableKeyEvents:true,
    listeners:{
        keydown:function(combo,e){
            if(e.getKey() === e.V && e.ctrlKey){
                //get Clipboard data here
                combo.preventKeyUpEvent = e.V;
                e.stopEvent();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can add [paste](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste) event listener to your combo (its picker actually) and get clipboard data using methods of [ClipboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent) interface, like this:

```
combo.getEl().addListener(
    'paste',
    function(event, element, options) {
        var clipboardData = event.browserEvent.clipboardData;
        console.log(clipboardData.getData('Text'));
    }
);
```

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ccf)

Comment: Thanks Sergey..This is working and what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are doing wrong, but it does work in my IE11 if I add `console.log(window.clipboardData)` to your fiddle:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Tag',{
            renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
            createNewOnEnter:true,
            store:[1,2,3],
            enableKeyEvents:true,
            listeners:{
                keydown:function(combo,e){

                    if(e.getKey() === e.V && e.ctrlKey){
                        console.log(window.clipboardData);
                        combo.preventKeyUpEvent = e.V;
                        e.stopEvent();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I cannot recommend using it, though, since `window.clipboardData` is IE only. You should use the [W3C clipboard API instead](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/), which is a draft for standardization and [already implemented in all recent browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard).

Comment: Thanks for you time Alex.I wanted to use extjs control.